# Keeping mutable objects sorted in TreeSets at all times

Tags: java, treeset

It came to my notice that a TreeSet doesn't keep the mutable objects in sorted order if object attribute values are changed later on. For example,

```
public class Wrap { 
    static TreeSet<Student> ts = new TreeSet<Student>(new Comparator<Student>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {            
            return o1.age - o2.age;
        }       
    }); 
    public static void main(String []args){
        Student s = new Student(10);
        ts.add(s); 
        ts.add(new Student(50));
        ts.add(new Student(30));
        ts.add(new Student(15));
        System.out.println(ts);
        s.age = 24;      //Here I change the age of a student in the TreeSet
        System.out.println(ts);     
    }
}
class Student{
    int age;
    Student(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }   
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [age=" + age + "]";
    }   
}
```

The output is :

```
[Student [age=10], Student [age=15], Student [age=30], Student [age=50]]
[Student [age=24], Student [age=15], Student [age=30], Student [age=50]]
```

After I change the age of a particular student, and then print the TreeSet, the Set seems no longer in sorted order. Why does this happen? and how to keep it sorted always?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> ***Why does this happen?***

Because the set cannot *monitor* all its objects for changes... How would it be able to do that?!

Same problem arises for `HashSets`. You can't change values affecting an objects hash-code when a `HashSet` holds the object.

> ***and how to keep it sorted always?***

You typically remove the element from the set, modify it, and then reinsert it. In other words, change

```
s.age = 24;      //Here I change the age of a student in the TreeSet
```

to

```
ts.remove(s);
s.age = 24;      //Here I change the age of a student in the TreeSet
ts.add(s);
```

You can also use for example a list, and call `Collections.sort` on the list each time you've modified an object.

Comment: Remove / reinsert will probably be faster (O(log n) as opposed to O(n log n)).

Comment: Never said it did. I said "you can also use a list..." in which case `Collections.sort` works fine.

Comment: A related gotcha: I tried a listener that, for any modification to any item would try to refresh the sorting by making a new `TreeSet` instance and calling `addAll(old)`.  (This is equivalent to the constructor that takes a SortedSet of items.)  When `old` is a `SortedSet` with the same comparator, there's a JDK optimization that copies its now-incorrect ordering to the new set.  To fix this, you can use an intermediate: `addAll(new HashSet<>(old))`

Comment: I doubt that's a supported use case. It may very well be the case that an object is completely lost if it's modified after insertion.

Answer (score 9):

You could make use of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Let your `TreeSet` implement [`Observer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and let your `Student` extend [`Observable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html). The only change you need to make is to hide the `age` field by encapsulation so that you have more internal control over the change.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class ObservableTreeSet<O extends Observable> extends TreeSet<O> implements Observer {

    public ObservableTreeSet(Comparator<O> comparator) {
        super(comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(O element) {
        element.addObserver(this);
        return super.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void update(Observable element, Object arg) {
        remove(element);
        add((O) element);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Student extends Observable {

    private int age;

    Student(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        if (this.age != age) {
            setChanged();
        }

        this.age = age;

        if (hasChanged()) {
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [age=" + age + "]";
    }
}
```

Now do a `new ObservableTreeSet` instead of `new TreeSet`.

```
static TreeSet<Student> ts = new ObservableTreeSet<Student>(new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }
});
```

It's ugly at first sight, but you end up with no changes in the main code. Just do a `s.setAge(24)` and the `TreeSet` will "reorder" itself.

Comment: A nice proposal but I have a problem with that solution. Since i call `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` only for changed properties which I use in `compareTo()`, `remove(element)` doesn't work because it uses `compareTo()` to check if element exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic problem with Maps and Sets. The values are inserted using the hashCode/equals/compare at the moment of insertion, and if the values on which these methods are based change, then the structures can screw up.

One way would be to remove the item from the set and re-add it after the value has been changed. Then it would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Glazed Lists can help: http://www.glazedlists.com/

I use it for its EventList and haven't tried sorting. But on their home page they list the main features:

> **Live Sorting** means your table stays sorted as your data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is best to manually keep your sorted `Set`/`Map` continuously consistent (see the strategy mentioned by @aioobe).

However, sometimes this is not an option. In these cases we can try this:

```
if (treeSet.contains(item)) {
    treeSet.remove(item);
    treeSet.add(item);
}
```

or with a map:

```
if (treeMap.containsKey(key)) {
    Value value = treeMap.get(key);
    treeMap.remove(key);
    treeMap.put(key, value);
}
```

But this will not work correctly, because even `containsKey` can result with an incorrect result.

So what can we do with a dirty map? **How can we refresh a single key without having to rebuild the entire map?** Here is a utility class to solve this problem (can be easily converted to handle sets):

```
public class MapUtil {

    /**
     * Rearranges a mutable key in a (potentially sorted) map
     * 
     * @param map
     * @param key
     */
    public static <K, V> void refreshItem(Map<K, V> map, K key) {
        SearchResult<K, V> result = MapUtil.searchMutableKey(map, key);
        if (result.found) {
            result.iterator.remove();
            map.put(key, result.value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Searches a mutable key in a (potentially sorted) map
     * 
     * Warning: currently this method uses equals() to check equality.
     * The returned object contains three fields:
     * - `found`: true iff the key found
     * - `value`: the value under the key or null if `key` not found
     * - `iterator`: an iterator pointed to the key or null if `key` not found
     * 
     * @param map
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public static <K, V> SearchResult<K, V> searchMutableKey(Map<K, V> map, K key) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entryIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<K, V> entry = entryIterator.next();
            if (key.equals(entry.getKey())) {
                return new SearchResult<K, V>(true, entry.getValue(), entryIterator);
            }
        }
        return new SearchResult<K, V>(false, null, null);
    }

    public static class SearchResult<K, V> {

        final public boolean found;

        final public V value;

        final public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator;

        public SearchResult(boolean found, V value, Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator) {
            this.found = found;
            this.value = value;
            this.iterator = iterator;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the iteration order, and you don't want to use the extra functionality of `TreeSet` (`headSet()` etc.), then use `HashSet` with custom iterator. Also, there is a major problem with your example: two students of the same age (often it happens) make conflict.

A possible solution:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MagicSet<Student> ts = new MagicSet<Student>(new Comparator<Student>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
                return student1.age - student2.age;
            }

        });

        Student s = new Student(10);

        ts.add(s); 
        ts.add(new Student(50));
        ts.add(new Student(30));
        ts.add(new Student(15));

        System.out.println(ts); // 10, 15, 30, 50
        s.age = 24;
        System.out.println(ts); // 15, 24, 30, 50
    }

    public static class Student {

        public int age;

        public Student(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Student [age=" + age + "]";
        }

    }

    public static class MagicSet<T> extends HashSet<T> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2736789057225925894L;

        private final Comparator<T> comparator;

        public MagicSet(Comparator<T> comparator) {
            this.comparator = comparator;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<T>();
            Iterator<T> superIterator = super.iterator();
            while (superIterator.hasNext()) {
                sortedList.add(superIterator.next());
            }
            Collections.sort(sortedList, comparator);
            return sortedList.iterator();
        }

    }

}
```